# Implementing Co-Browsing

Tags: java, servlets, sip, conferencing

I need more information or ideas as to how to implement co-browsing.
Here are few of the links I went through

http://www.kolabora.com/news/2007/03/22/cobrowsing_tools_and_technology_a.htm

http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/cobrowsing_with_clavardon.php#

http://www.retailsystemsresearch.com/_document/summary/877

http://www.cs.odu.edu/~maly/edmedia.doc

Though I got an idea of how co browsing works but 
I now I need to know how it can be implemented..

Which implementation would be good...servlet based or implementing SIP...

I need lightweight implementation of the same

I want multiple users to view videos mainly on web.

Can it be done in any other way??
anyone give me more information and usefull links

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how cobrowsing applies to SIP?

Comment: @newbie were you able to find any solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

A co-browsing solution that might fit your needs: http://www.unblu.com

Answer (score 0):

Did you check wikipedia?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobrowsing